# How to connect from asp.net web site to sql server with windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

My connection string is

```
Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Persist Security Info=False;
```

i have in web config

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

From the server i can browse the site and data come from DB.

From another station in network, i can see the site but data is not coming from server.

Comment: can you connect using windows authentication with SSMS (from the remore station...)?

Comment: in the server i can see the data in the web site, and with SSMS using windows auth,from the remote server i can login with windows auth